# With devise, how can I dynamically set config options such as password length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my application, I want users to be able to specify their own password security.

I'm using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and the [Devise Security Extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension) looks good.

The downside to the suggested configurations in the Devise Security Extension is that it all takes place in the devise.rb config file in the initializers directory. I would like to be able to selectively include certain configuration options.

I guess I could, for example, enable everything, and then at the user model, override methods such as `need_change_password?` in my user model for expiring passwords. But I'm not sure if that's the best approach.

Any guidance as to best practices is much appreciated.